# Android Chrome not cache big file even fetching by force-cache

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-chrome

I want to load and cache a big data file from the server.
The dict.json file is about 30MB big.

```js
fetch('/data/dict.json', {cache: "force-cache"})
```

In Desktop Chrome, it works as expected.

However, in android chrome, it still load the file everytime from the server, not from the cache when I refresh the page.

How to make it get cached in android chrome?

Comment: This flag not really force the browser to save the results in the cache it's force to check if there a cached results before doing the request

Comment: It's better to use service worker to help you do the thing you wanna do